# What is the probability that the bird is an ivory-billed woodpecker?

Tags: probability

A thrilled birdwatcher suspects she has spotted an ivory-billed woodpecker. Skeptics contend
that it was probably a common pileated woodpecker.

•Ivory-billed woodpeckers are a class 6 species, defined as “definitely or probably extinct.”
The chance of seeing an ivory-billed woodpecker can be estimated as one in a million.
The chance of seeing a pileated woodpecker can be estimated as one in 50.

•The birdwatcher estimates her bird’s length at 19 inches. That’s on the large side for
a pileated woodpecker, which has a 10% chance of being that size.  An ivory-billed
woodpecker has a 70% chance of being that size.

What is the probability that the bird is an ivory-billed woodpecker?
(Note: this answer is a very small number; you can leave it in terms of the component
probabilities without multiplying, dividing, and adding it up.)

Comment: Welcome to MSE !  Please follow the guidelines outlined by [How to ask a good question?](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and [How to ask a homework question?](https://goo.gl/Fyfb22).

Comment: This appears to be a straightforward application of [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

Comment: @lulu if you don't mind could you work this problem out. I'm new to the topic and I'm still not quite clear on it.

Comment: Please take a stab at it yourself first.  I'll then comment on it.  As a hint to get you started:  I think the stated probabilities are a bit confusing and I would interpret them as saying that there are $\frac {1000000}{50}=20000$ times as many pileated as ivory-billed woodpeckers (and that each bird is equally likely to be observed).